# Is there a CICS (COBOL) wrapper for zOS connect having Depending on clause?

Tags: containers, channel, cics, zos-connect-ee

Is there a CICS (COBOL) wrapper program example for a z/OS connect?

I am have to use DEPENDING CLAUSE for the same. So far I am new to the z/OS thing.
I have to use channels and containers.

An example, if any, please.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a wrapper program?  The tooling for z/OS Connect supports Occurs Depending On as long as the object (the field containing the number of occurrances) is in the same structure as the variably occurring field.

For example, z/OS Connect supports this:

```
01 My-structure.
   03 Some-data              pic x(13).
   03 Data-count             pic s9(4) comp.
   03 Lots-of-data           pic x(20)
         occurs 1 to 6 times 
         depending on Data-count.
```

But if "Data-count" is not defined within "My-structure", it is not supported.

See my next answer on a technique to handle occurs depending on if your copybooks are not structured the way that z/OS Connect supports.

Comment: HI Leigh, I have to call a CoolGen program using that wrapper. That why I am asking how this CICS wrapper have to be defined. We used simple logic till now. But with depending on clause its getting difficult. Can you please help on how the containers used to be defined and passed on the values.